# Trouble printing Digital Signature

Tags: pdfsharp

I have created a pdf document using ModelDoc. After creating it, I am using PDFSharp to insert a digital signature in the document.

The digital signature is seen properly and I am also able to perform normal task of signature validation.

However, the digital signature is not printed when I print the document. I have already tried using "Document and markup" and "Document and stamps".

However, the signature is still not being printed. Here is the code for digital signature.

```
void ISignatureAppearanceHandler.DrawAppearance(XGraphics gfx, XRect rect)
    {
        string signtext = "This is a digital signature";

        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 8.0, XFontStyle.Regular);
        XPoint xPoint = new XPoint(0.0, 0.0);

        gfx.DrawRectangle(
            XBrushes.LightBlue, xPoint.X, 
            xPoint.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height
        );

        XTextFormatter xTextFormatter = new XTextFormatter(gfx);

        xTextFormatter.DrawString(
            signtext, font, 
            new XSolidBrush(
                XColor.FromKnownColor(XKnownColor.Black)
            ), 
            new XRect(
                xPoint.X, xPoint.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height
            ),  
           XStringFormats.TopLeft
        );
    }
```

Comment: Could be a bit more clear on what you expect to happen?   Specifically, why would a digital signature or any indication of a digital signature be printed? It feels like you are expected a particular operating system and PDF printer behavior and have not shared the particulars.

Comment: Hi Charles, The print is necessary for legal reasons. It happens on all OS and does not depend on any specific printer. I tried the default sample code available with PDFSharp but it has same problem. If you manually put a digital signature using Adobe, it prints without any problem. I think this may be some problem in PDFSharp library.

Comment: @AjitVaze, please check if the answer I just posted helps

Comment: Right-click on the signature, choose "View signed document", print that with Markup/Stamps.

Comment: I tried that as well but it is not working. I have mentioned it in the original question which I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try Printing your text before initiating PdfSignatureHandler it worked fine for me.

```
 private static void SignExisting()
    {
        double height = 40;
        double width = 200;
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;    
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(path);
        PdfPage pp = pdfDocument.Pages[0];
        var cert = GetCertificate();
        string signtext = "Digitaly Signed by " + cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);           
       XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pp);       
            XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);
            gfx.DrawString(signtext, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(x, pp.Height - y, pp.Width, pp.Height), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
            gfx.DrawString("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(x, pp.Height - y, pp.Width, pp.Height), XStringFormats.TopLeft);  
        PdfSignatureOptions options = new PdfSignatureOptions
        {
            ContactInfo = cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false),
            Location = cert.Subject,
            Reason = "",
            Rectangle = new XRect(x, y, width, height),
            AppearanceHandler = new SignAppearenceHandler()
        };
        PdfSignatureHandler pdfSignatureHandler = new PdfSignatureHandler(cert, null, options);
        pdfSignatureHandler.AttachToDocument(pdfDocument);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfDocument.Save(stream);
    }
```